# Why the html content of an "img" element cannot be transferred to another element using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, image, innerhtml, setattribute

I have two elements and I would like to transfer the html content of an element to the other one. However, for some reason that I don't understand at this moment, it doesn't work;

```
let firstElement = document.createElement('div'); 
let secElement = document.createElement('img'); 

secElement.innerHTML = "<img src = 'head.png'/>";
firstElement = secElement.innerHTML;

document.body.append(firstElement);
```

If I run this code, the image contained in the "secElement" and transferred into the "firstElement" is not shown. Also, if I check the "firstElement" in the console, its content is displayed as ''.

I also cannot use the "setAttribute()" method to add an attribute to the "firstElement" because I receive the error "Uncaught TypeError: firstElement.setAttribute is not a function".

Why is this happening?

Can you please help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: After 4th line, firstElement is no longer an Html element. You are overriding its value with string. that is why functions such as setAttribute is not working.

Comment: [img](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#technical_summary) is a void element, it can't contain HTML or any other content. You need to set `outerHTML` of the element, if you want redefine it using a string.

Comment: A HTML string is not the same as a DOM object. To Javascript, a DOM object is an object it can work with. A HTML string is just a string. Whether that string contains "hello" or "<div/>" makes no difference to Javascript. Both are just text. If you wish to add a src attribute to `secElement`, you should do `secElement.src = "head.png";` instead of using a string.